# How get the value from push pin image in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, selenium, google-maps-api-3, webdriver

When I search for a place it will display the location along with the **number** in the **map pointer** (overlay pin), but I want to print/retrieve that number.

I cannot get the number because it is showing as an image, which does not have a corresponding attribute value in the HTML page. See the screenshot bellow:

[image]

```html
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 26px; height: 43px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer; left: 809px; top: 249px; z-index: 291;" title="">
<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 26px; height: 43px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png" draggable="false"/>
</div>
```

```
<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 26px; height: 43px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer; left: 809px; top: 249px; z-index: 291;" title="">
<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 26px; height: 43px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png" draggable="false"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The purpose of a question on this website is to ask a question. Where is your question?

Comment: Recently started using StackOverflow. So I don't know how to ask exactly. -- I have seen someone from support team has edited my question now it looks good. thank you very much for supporting.

Comment: My Question is I want to print the number in the console in my selenium web driver script in my testing framework. - Thanks

Comment: 1. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 2. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get the value because it is rendering as image. We had same issue and asked developer not to render as image in QA environment. But the problem will be the page took long time to load. Another way is they have given some API to get the value of it.